# Update the global variable

Tags: javascript

My code snippet first:

```
let GLOBAL_VAR_A = 'string1';
let GLOBAL_VAR_B = 'string2';
let GLOBAL_VAR_C = []; // Empty array
let GLOBAL_VAR_D = []; // Empty array

...

start = async () => {  
    ...
    if(...) {
        await updateNews(GLOBAL_VAR_A, GLOBAL_VAR_B, GLOBAL_VAR_C, GLOBAL_VAR_D);
        console.log(GLOBAL_VAR_C); // => [] (empty) (NOT OK)
        console.log(GLOBAL_VAR_D); // => [object Object] = nextNews (OK!!)
    ...
}
};

updateNews = async (sourcePath, webResource, previousNews, nextNews) => {
    previousNews = await getPreviousNews(sourcePath, previousNews);
    console.log('FFF = ' + previousNews); // => FFF = [object Object] (Ok)
    ...
    nextNews.push({
            id: i + 1,
            title: justGottenNews[i].title,
            url: justGottenNews[i].link
    });   
}

getPreviousNews = async (sourcePath, previousNews) => {
    let data = await fs.readFileSync(sourcePath, 'utf8');
    prevNews = previousNews.concat(JSON.parse(data));
    return prevNews;
};

...
```

My question (issue) is the following:

When I call the function **updateNews()** I pass there some arguments - global variables. **GLOBAL_VAR_C** by default is an empty array which is passed to the **updateNews()** function. Further this variable is passed to **getPreviousNews()** function. This function returns a new array (**prevNews**) - concatenation of the empty one and received from the file.

Then I want to re-define a value of the variable **previousNews**. Inside the function **updateNews()** its value is correct (returned array).

How can I re-define a value of passed **GLOBAL_VAR_C** variable further? It should be equal to **previousNews**. But when I console log it still empty array is returned.

Interesting point is that **nextNews** is updated inside **updateNews()** function (method *push()*) and **GLOBAL_VAR_D** is updated as well

Comment: You never update that array. That's why you get its value unchanged - you just pass it around three times and never change it.

Comment: And why would you pass global vars into function calls anyway? The whole point of having a global variable is that it can be accessed from any function.

Comment: Because I call the function **updateNews()** several times with different set of arguments. I've shown the first call of it. After it's been finished I call it again but with another variables.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to update the Global variable with *push()* method inside **updateNews()**

Comment: [As I said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57298403/update-the-global-variable#comment101090856_57298403) - you never actually updated the contents of the array.